# How to display all data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I need help with showing all of a certain piece of data. my code is below

```
const [server, setServer] = useState()

const getServer = useCallback(async () => {
   // const id = what do I do here?? 
   
    const unsubscribe = firebase.db.collection("servers").doc('S7FlCYEvxIVDs7MRymnK').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        setServer(snapshot.data())
    })
    return unsubscribe
},[props.server])

useEffect(() => {
    getServer()
}, [props])

console.log(server)
```

you can see I want to replace the hard coded doc info with an id variable, so in my project I can show multiple servers instead of a hard coded one I choose.

Comment: Are you asking how to [listen for realtime updates to multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection)?

Comment: How would you get the doc id to pass ?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, could you please clarify your question. Do you want to get specific document from the `server` collection or get all the documents from the `server` collection? Your query contradicts to your question title and your statement here: `so in my project I can show multiple servers instead of a hard coded one I choose.`